# Grub rescue failure to boot

Tags: boot, grub2

When I put command 1s it's saying "unknown command"
When I put `grub rescue> set`

```
Cmdpath=(hd0)
Prefix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub
Root=hd0,1
```

Are What are coming up.

```
Linux/boot//vimlinuz root=/dev/sda1
Says: unknown command
```

Please I need help.

Is there a way of formating the hdd through grub rescue? Booting is completely failing, I have even put iso image of ubuntu on flash disk but seems it's not capturing it either.

Comment: I think the command format is usually something like "set root=(hd0, 1)". But I don't use it very often *knock on silicone*

Answer (score 0):

```
set prefix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub
```

then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
insmod normal
```

press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Could you clarify a bit?  Where does the OP have to type this command?  What is it supposed to do?